WinForms AppMenu.xml menu building issue
I'have following xml file. Based on it MenuBuilder.cs builds app menu.
It works good enough for Debug and Release modes for VS but doesn't work for published app.
Publishing directory is "Compiled". I've running .exe file from it and don't see many menu items (some are builded, some not)
Can you give me an advice about what can happened?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--
  Описание структуры меню приложения (дерево)
  "AppMenu" - root-элемент
  "Item" - элемент меню. Может обладать следующими атрибутами (*) - обязательный атрибут:
    Text (string) - текст, который отображен в пункте меню (*)
    Name (string) - уникальное имя элемента, по которому к нему можно получить доступ из программы
    ModuleName (string) - Namespace.ClassName модуля, привязанного к этому пункту меню
    OnClick (string) - имя обработчика события OnClick данного элемента меню
    MDIList (string: true|false) - отобржается ли в этом пункте меню список окон MDI-приложения
    Shortcut (string) - название комбинации клавиш для быстрого вызова данного пункта меню
    Point (string: center|point) - центр, магазин.
-->
<!--
  <Item Text="&amp;Настройки" OnClick="_Settings" />
-->

<AppMenu>
  <Item Text="С&amp;правочники">
    <Item Text="Товары" ModuleName="GoodsList.GoodsList" Shortcut="AltF3"/>
    <Item Text="Виды продукции" ModuleName="Directorys.TypesGoodMenu"
              Point="center"/>
    <Item Text="Ресурсы" ModuleName="Directorys.DirectoryResources"/>
    <Item Text="Производители" ModuleName="Directorys.DirectoryMakers" Point="center"/>
    <Item Text="Торговые точки" ModuleName="Directorys.DirectoryPoints" Point="center"/>
    <Item Text="Привязки супервайзеров и директоров региона" ModuleName="Directorys.PointSupervisorsMenu" Point="center"/>
    <Item Text="Контрагенты" ModuleName="Directorys.DirectoryCounterParts"/>
    <Item Text="Владельцы" ModuleName="Directorys.DirectoryOwners" Point="center"/>
    <ItemCatMan Text="Категорийные менеджеры" Point="center">
      <Item Text="Менеджеры" ModuleName="ControlChoice.ControlManagers"/>
      <Item Text="План продаж по категориям" ModuleName="ControlChoice.CategoriesSalesPlansMenu"/>
      <Item Text="Выполнение планов менеджерами">
        <Item Text="Расчетные коэффициенты прироста для выставления плана на месяц" ModuleName="ControlChoice.Managers.ManagersPlansCompletions.CalculatedGrowthFactorsForSettingMonthlyPlanModule"/>
        <Item Text="Расчетные коэффициенты для выставления плана на квартал КМ" ModuleName="ControlChoice.Managers.ManagersPlansCompletions.CalculationCoefficientsForSettingPlanForCategoryManagerQuarterModule"/>
        <Item Text="План/Факт" ModuleName="ControlChoice.Managers.ManagersPlansCompletions.PlansForProfitsSalesTurnoversAndDeptsModule"/>
        <Item Text="Квартальный отчет для начисления зарплаты КМ" ModuleName="ControlChoice.Managers.ManagersPlansCompletions.QuarterlyReportForCategoryManagerSalaryCalculating"/>
        <Item Text="Отчет по выполнению квартального плана КМ" ModuleName="ControlChoice.Managers.ManagersPlansCompletions.PenetrationPlanFactWithIlliquidStockShareForMoreThanSixMonthInTheTotalBalancesOfAccountableCategoriesTheShareOfOverdueOrDefectiveGoodsAndAverageMarginPercentModule"/>
      </Item>
      <Item Text="План по прибыли по категориям" ModuleName="ControlChoice.CategoriesProfitPlansMenu"/>
      <Item Text="План коэф. прибыли по категориям" ModuleName="ControlChoice.CategoriesProfitCoefPlansMenu"/>
      <Item Text="План оборачиваемости по категориям" ModuleName="ControlChoice.CategoriesTurnoverPlansMenu"/>
    </ItemCatMan>
  </Item>
</AppMenu>


When it is WinForms why the WPF tag?
